# Configuration file with Python functionality

Tags: python, parsing

I'm working on quite complicated scientific project.

I decided to use a configuration file for model description. However it was quite complicated to parse all strings after `ConfigParser` and convert every option to required objects, so I would like to avoid this long/boring code.

I wrote very simple parser which converts all options into Python objects by default. With some additional name resolving I've got a simple, elegant and useful solution.

```
import os,sys,ConfigParser, types
import logging
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def nameresolv(item,nspace):
        copir = item.split("@")
        if len(copir) < 2: 
                res = item
        else:
                res = ''
                for pre,var in map(None,copir[::2],copir[1::2]):
                        if pre != None: res += pre
                        if var == None: continue
                        var = var.split(":")
                        if len(var) != 2: return None
                        if not var[0] in nspace : return None
                        if not var[1] in nspace[var[0]] : return None
                        res += 'nspace["%s"]["%s"]'%tuple(var)
        copir = res.split("$")
        if len(copir) < 2: return res
        res = ''
        for pre,var in map(None,copir[::2],copir[1::2]):
                if pre != None: res += pre
                if var == None: continue
                var = var.split(":")
                if len(var) != 2: return None
                if not var[0] in nspace : return None
                if not var[1] in nspace[var[0]] : return None
                if type(nspace[var[0]][var[1]]) is types.LambdaType and nspace[var[0]][var[1]].__name__ == '<lambda>':
                        res += 'nspace["%s"]["%s"]'%tuple(var)
                else:
                        res += str(nspace[var[0]][var[1]])
        return unicode(res)

def confreader(filename,nspace = {}):
        """
        Reads file with configurations and returns dictionary with sections
        and options. All options will be turned into python objects (DON'T 
        FORGET PUT ALL STRING OPTIONS WITHIN QUOTES).

        You can use @SECTION:OPTION@ notation to refer to existed python object,
        or $SECTION:OPTION$ to convert object back into a string and insert a string.

        Returns option dictionary or {}. 
        Empty dictionary indicates error with file opening, reading or parsing.

        If confreader couldn't turn option into some python object, this 
        options is skipped and Warning message will put in logger.

        """
        if      filename == None:
                return nspace
        if not os.access(filename,os.R_OK):
                return nspace
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.optionxform=str
        try:
                config.read( filename )
        except :
                return nspace
        for section in config.sections():
                if not section in nspace: nspace[section]={}
                for option in config.options(section):
                        if option in nspace[section]:
                                logging.error("Name conflict option \'%s\' exists in section [\'%s\']"%(option,section) ) 
                                return {}                               
                        xitem = unicode( config.get(section,option) )
                        item = nameresolv(xitem,nspace)
                        if item == None:
                                logging.error("Problem with resolving option in  [\'%s\']\'%s\'=\'%s\'"%(section,option,item) ) 
                                return {}
                        try:
                                exec "nspace[\""+section+"\"][\""+option+"\"]="+item
                        except :
                                logging.warning("Problem with reading configuration from the %s"%filename) 
                                logging.warning("Cannot read section: \'%s\', option: \'%s\'"%(section,option) )
                                logging.warning("        %s"%item)
                                logging.warning("!!!! SKIPPED IT !!!!")
                                pass

        return nspace
```

An example:

```
#FILE: examples.cfg

[LINKS]
x = ["a","b"]
y = [ @LINKS:x@, "c"]
z = ["x"]+@LINKS:x@+["c","d"]

[COMPUTATIONS]
x = 5
y = 7
x+y = @COMPUTATIONS:x@+@COMPUTATIONS:y@
x*y = @COMPUTATIONS:x@*@COMPUTATIONS:y@
lst = range(@COMPUTATIONS:x*y@)
filter = @COMPUTATIONS:lst@[@COMPUTATIONS:x@:@COMPUTATIONS:y@]

[FUNCTIONS]
fun = lambda x: x**2+32
operation = @FUNCTIONS:fun@(12)
fun(x+y) = @FUNCTIONS:fun@(@COMPUTATIONS:x+y@)

[LINKS_AND_STRINGS]
x = "I"
y = "Python"
exmp1 = @LINKS_AND_STRINGS:x@+' love '+@LINKS_AND_STRINGS:y@
#same but with string resolving. Please not that sting inside ' '
exmp2 = '$LINKS_AND_STRINGS:x$ love $LINKS_AND_STRINGS:y$'
#BUT this will create an a problem
#exmp3 = '@LINKS_AND_STRINGS:x@ love @LINKS_AND_STRINGS:y@'
#You can resolve variable into string
exmp4 = 'In my $LINKS_AND_STRINGS:y$ + conf, $LINKS_AND_STRINGS:x$ can     resolve x+y = $COMPUTATIONS:x+y$ inline'

#END  examples.cfg
```

And the result of parsing:

```
>>> from pyconf import pyconf 
>>> cfg = pyconf("examples.cfg")
>>> for name in cfg: print name
... 
COMPUTATIONS
FUNCTIONS
LINKS
LINKS_AND_STRINGS
>>>
>>> for name  in cfg["LINKS"]: print name,"=",cfg["LINKS"][name]
... 
y = [['a', 'b'], 'c']
x = ['a', 'b']
z = ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
>>> for name  in cfg["COMPUTATIONS"]: print name,"=",cfg["COMPUTATIONS"][name]
... 
filter = [5, 6]
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
x+y = 12
y = 7
x = 5
x*y = 35
>>>
>>> for name  in cfg["FUNCTIONS"]: print name,"=",cfg["FUNCTIONS"][name]
... 
fun = <function <lambda> at 0xa5841ec>
operation = 176
fun(x+y) = 176
>>>
>>> for name  in cfg["LINKS_AND_STRINGS"]: print name,"=",cfg["LINKS_AND_STRINGS"][name]
... 
y = Python
x = I
exmp4 = In my Python + conf, I can resolve x+y = 12 inline
exmp1 = I love Python
exmp2 = I love Python
>>>
```

I'd like to ask Python gurus for their opinion and any suggestions on code improvement. I'll appreciate any ideas on making this code better. Yep, feel free to use it if you'd like.

Comment: it might be helpful to provide an example of how you actually intend to use this programme for model description. There might be easier ways than using a config file.

Comment: Thank you for comment @Stuart. I used to use a lot of different approaches: XML, SQL (SQLight), just python and NEURON[http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/] structures and so on. When I started my new project I have found that config file seems to be well fitted for my model description. However it was hard to describe some computation procedures in config (like some parameter gradients in a population of neurons). So in this solution, python functionality appears in config file only when we need it. Yes and I call lambda functions from code also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, some general style comments:

1. Take a look at [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide. This gives some really nice pointers on how to style your code.
2. Avoid multiple statements per line. You do this a lot. Putting multiple statements on a single line makes the code more difficult to follow. So instead of this:

   ```
   if pre != None: res += pre
   ```

   use this style:

   ```
   if pre is not None:
       res += pre
   ```
3. Use better variable names. When thinking of names, its better to err on the side of being too verbose than being too terse. Some shortened names are fine due to a global understanding of what they mean (i.e. `str`, `char`, etc.). Applying this idea:

   ```
   result
   ```

   is better than:

   ```
   res
   ```
4. Whitespace is your friend. Place single blank lines to separate logical sections of code. Also, PEP8 gives [a nice overview](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) of where space in statements is appropriate and when its not. A (somewhat extreme) example:

   ```
   # This is bad whitespace
   foo=  list ( [2,3,4,   5 ])

   # This is 'correct' whitespace
   foo = list([2, 3, 4, 5])
   ```
5. Technically your indentation is fine. However, conventional Python uses a 4-space indentation level to mark deeper blocks of code.
6. In Python, the naming convention for basically everything is to use `underscores_in_names`. I don't see any `camelCase` or `PascalCase` in your code (which is good). However, your function names `confreader` and `nameresolv` should be formatted like so: `conf_reader` and `name_resolv`.

   Since we're already speaking on function names, typically you want to start function names with a verb:

   ```
   # This is better than...
   def resolve_name():

   # this.
   def name_resolve():
   ```
7. Each import of individual modules should get their own line:

   ```
   # No
   import os, sys, logging

   # Yes
   import os
   import sys
   import logging

   # This is also fine
   from mymodule import foo, bar, baz
   ```

---

Now onto some improvements:

1. In your `nameresolv` function, you have a for loop where you use `map` with a `None` function. What this does according to the docs is:

   > If function is None, the identity function is assumed;

   So your code works. However, in Python 3.X this actually errors. Essentially what you want to do is get pairs of consecutive elements in an iterable. To do this, we can use the `zip` function:

   ```
   for pre, var in zip(copir[::2], copir[1::2]):
   ```
2. Because we now use the `zip` function, we can remove the `None` check and simply append `pre` each time. This is because `pre` will either be a necessary string or it will be `''`. Either way it is fine to append to `res`.
3. Inside the for loop described above, you can combine multiple of your if statements:

   ```
   if len(var) != 2: return None
   if not var[0] in nspace : return None
   if not var[1] in nspace[var[0]] : return None
   ```

   into:

   ```
   if len(var) != 2 or not var[0] in nspace or not var[1] in nspace[var[0]]:
       return None
   ```
4. When creating strings, using `str.format` is more preferred than using the `%` formatting notation. So your formatting statement would now look like this:

   ```
   res += 'nspace["{}"]["{}"]'.format(*var)
   ```
5. You could (and should) pull your for-loop into its own function. You essentially do the same loop twice. Seeing duplicated code is a sure-fire indicator that a function can be created:

   ```
   def build_result(split, namespace, check_lambda=False):
       result = ''
       for prefix, var in zip(split[::2], split[1::2]):
           if not var:
               continue

           try:
               # This will error if len(var.split()) != 2
               section, option = var.split(':')
           except ValueError:
               return None

           if section not in namespace or option not in namespace[section]:
               return None

           if not check_lambda:
               result += 'namespace["{}"]["{}"]'.format(section, option)
               continue

           value = namespace[section][option]
           if isinstance(value, types.LambdaType) and value.__name__ == '<lambda>':
               result += 'namespace["{}"]["{}"]'.format(section, option)
           else:
               result += str(value)

       return result
   ```

---

With my suggestions, your code now looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import types
import logging
from configparser import ConfigParser


def is_lambda(value):
    return isinstance(value, types.LambdaType) and value.__name__ == '<lambda>'

def build_result(split, namespace, check_lambda=False):
    result = ''
    for prefix, var in zip(split[::2], split[1::2]):
        if not var:
            continue

        try:
            # This will error if len(var.split()) != 2
            section, option = var.split(':')
        except ValueError:
            return None

        if section not in namespace or option not in namespace[section]:
            return None

        if not check_lambda:
            result += 'namespace["{}"]["{}"]'.format(section, option)
            continue

        value = namespace[section][option]
        if is_lambda(value):
            result += 'namespace["{}"]["{}"]'.format(section, option)
        else:
            result += str(value)

    return result

def resolve_name(item, namespace):
    # Check "'@' not in" to save from having to call `split`
    if '@' not in item: 
        result = item
    else:
        result = build_result(item.split('@'), namespace)

    # Check for error before next build_result
    if result == None:
        return result

    # Same reasoning as above.
    if '$' not in result:
        return result

    return unicode(build_result(result.split("$"), namespace, check_lambda=True))        

def parse_config(filename, namespace={}):
    if not filename or not os.access(filename,os.R_OK):
        return namespace

    config = ConfigParser()
    config.optionxform = str

    # This should not error. If a file could not be read, it will skip it.
    # Worst case, config will be an empty list.
    config.read(filename)
    for section in config.sections():
        if section not in namespace:
            namespace[section] = {}

        for option in config.options(section):
            if option in namespace[section]:
                logging.error("Name conflict option '{}' exists in section ['{}']".format(option, section)) 
                return {}

            item = resolve_name(unicode(config.get(section, option)), namespace)
            if not item:
                logging.error("Problem with resolving option in  ['{}']'{}' = {}'".format(section, option, item))
                return {}

            try:
                exec "namespace['{}']['{}'] = {}".format(section, option, item)
            except Exception:
                logging.warning("Problem with reading configuration from the {}".format(filename))
                logging.warning("Cannot read section: '{}', option: '{}'".format(section, option))
                logging.warning("\t\t{}".format(item))
                logging.warning("!!!! SKIPPED IT !!!!")

    return namespace
```

Comment: [`if pre is not None`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2209781/1157100) is preferable to `if pre != None`.

Comment: To @DarinDouglass, I have got an error message in line 'if len(var) != 2 or not var[0] in nspace or not var[1] in nspace[var[0]]: return None' It seems we cannot concatenate conditions by or in this case. for example if `v=["a"]' the condition 'if len(v) == 2 or not "b" in v[2]: print v' returns an error 'Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> IndexError: list index out of range '

Comment: Is your code throwing an `IndexError`? The only place I see in `build_result` that could throw that error is the for loop statement (which is not the line you mentioned). Also, I guard against this error with my `section, option = var.split()` line. This assures that `var` has two parts to it (i.e `var[0]` and `var[1]` are valid indices).

Comment: To @DarinDouglass. I've found a lot of bugs in your code. Before I used just ideas to improve my code, but today I coped - pasted it. So I've edit code: there was extra column after lambda in the line 7; there were no closed parentheses for logging.warning function in lines 61-63. I add checking if result is None, otherwise it tries split None and end up with exception.

Comment: @user29689 Thanks for the extra pair of eyes. I wasn't able to test the code before my review went up.

Comment: What's bother me: $$ names resolving does not return an error if there is no required section or option. Instead it terminates without error and with None instead of string. But it is very hard to say why. In new code logic sneaks behind my back.... :(